# Удаление Sprite со сцены cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d

При удалении спрайта функциями `this->removeChild(sprite,true);` или  `this->removeChildByTag(1)`  или `sprite->removeFromParent();` вылетает игра. В чём заключается проблема? Вроде простенькая функция, а крашит всё приложение.

Вылетает с ошибкой

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x58 in tid 7163 (GLThread 1727), pid 7124 (nyName.GameName)

Листинг:

```
bool HelloWorld::init() {

if (!Scene::init()) {
    return false;
}

auto visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();


/////////////////////////////

//спрайт игрока
ship = Sprite::create("player.png");
ship->setScale(5);
ship->setPosition(30, 100);

//жизни
for(int i=0;i<lifes;i++){
    heart=Sprite::create("heart.png");
    heart->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + 30 + i * 20,visibleSize.height-10));
    heart->setScale(7);
    this->addChild(heart,2);
    hearts.push_back(heart);
}


//задний фон
background=Sprite::create("background.png");
background->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5,0.5));
background->setScale(10);
background->setPosition(Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().width/2,Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize().height/2);

//кнопка вверх
ui::Button *upButton=ui::Button::create("button_up.png","button_up.png");
upButton->setPosition(Vec2(30,80));
upButton->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::touchEventUp,this));

//кнопка вниз
ui::Button *downButton=ui::Button::create("button_down.png","button_down.png");
downButton->setPosition(Vec2(30,40));
downButton->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::touchEventDown,this));

//кнопка выстрела
ui::Button *shootButton=ui::Button::create("button_shoot.png","button_shoot.png");
shootButton->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width-50,50));
shootButton->addTouchEventListener(CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::touchEventShoot,this));

//добавляем элементы на сцену
this->addChild(upButton,2);
this->addChild(downButton,2);
this->addChild(shootButton,2);
this->addChild(background,0);
this->addChild(ship,1);

ship->setTag(1);
//this->removeChildByTag(ship);

//this->removeChildByName("player.png",true);
```

//this->removeChild(ship);

```
// ship->removeFromParent();

this->scheduleUpdate();
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::setGamePlaySpeed),1);

return true;
```

}

Comment: Отладчик может помочь или добавьте в нужные места исключения, и при обработке узнаете где ошибка

Comment: Ошибка явно при вызове функции для удаления спрайта. И это очень странно, так как это одна из базовых функций движка.

Comment: По тому, что вы выложили, лично я  не смогу помочь, поэтому только совет прозвучал...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, и на этом спасибо :3